# CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE and other permisions

Tags: linux, permissions, access-control

Who can see the content of my directory other than root? What is CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE? Can sysadmin give this privilege to my content to some user?

My understanding is someone who has CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE privilege can enter and see the content of any directory even if the permission in set to `chmod 600`. If so, is there a way I know if someone has that privilege to my directories.

My boss was trying very hard to spy on me, and lately I feel like he has convinced the system admin to do him some favor. Now he seem very familiar about what I am doing and about some files in my directory. I don't have anything to hide, but creeped out by being monitored by someone all the time.

If not by CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE is there anyway a person other than root see the content my directories?

Answer (score 4):

`CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE` is a [*process capability*](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man7/capabilities.7.html), it is not attached to specific files. For processes which have it in their effective capability set, DAC (read/write/execute) permission checks are bypassed completely. This is similar to how DAC permission checks are bypassed for root.

Granting shared access to files using such capability is extremely coarse (on/off), as it would skip *all* DAC access controls for ***everything***. Having the capability is essentially the same as being root [[1]](https://forums.grsecurity.net/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=2522). No responsible and competent system administrator would give root access to the machines they administrate for people who do not need it.

There are other access control mechanisms which allow fine grained configuration, for example [POSIX Access Control Lists (ACL)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man5/acl.5.html). They can be configured per file/directory basis to allow user(s)/group(s) access which normal DAC access would prevent.

If the system you are using is not managed by you, there is little you can do to get around the policies set by the system administrator. You could use additional file encryption on your client, which would keep your data private.

Your boss monitoring you at work is not really a technical problem, but a a social issue. A technical solution is not going to resolve the situation.

Comment: But is there any way I can check if my manager has the DAC permission? I do not have anything hide from him, but I wanted to know if someone has illegally obtained the permission. Even though I work for him, it is university owned system and I own the account. I wanted to be sure whether he has it before I raise it to the administration.

Comment: It is unlikely system administrator would configure such permission for anyone, because it would disable any DAC checks on the system. Without any specifics its not really possible to give a definite yes/no answer whether or how your boss might be monitoring your. See my updated answer, for details.

Comment: A competent sysadmin will not give management people root access, but it's not unheard of for an incompetent manager to demand that.